# window.g.cs file not found in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am new to wpf. I started learning login in wpf using MVVM. I found a very good link regarding this.[this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-WPF-Login-Navigate-7a8d34a0#content)

I downloaded a sample code from there but when I try to run that solution I'm getting this error.

```
Error   1   Source file 'C:\Users\pci218\Downloads\Easy WPF Login & Navigate Tutorial. Simple WPF Examples, in code-behind or MVVM\C#\EasyWpfLoginNavigateExample\obj\Debug\View\MainWindow.g.cs' could not be found    C:\Users\pci218\Downloads\Easy WPF Login %26 Navigate Tutorial. Simple WPF Examples%2c in code-behind or MVVM\C#\EasyWpfLoginNavigateExample\CSC    EasyWpfLoginNavigateExample
```

I clean and rebuild solution too, but it still says g.cs file not found. Please help me if anyone had faced the same issue.

Comment: which is the version of visual studio are you using ?

Comment: visual studio 2013

Comment: i tried to open in VS 2012 too.

Comment: just rename the folder name (example: EasyWpfLoginNavigateExample) after extracting and try rebuild it will work

Comment: renaming the folder worked for me in visual studio 2013

Comment: wow..that worked for me too..big thanks frebin :)

Comment: can you please mark it as answer ?

Comment: This Answer  Worked  for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just rename the folder name (example: EasyWpfLoginNavigateExample) after extracting and try rebuild it will work

this should solve the problem